# How do i take the first integer from left and right and sum it in 2 deffirent cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to take the first integer from left and put into a cell and the first integer from right and put into a cell.
I formattet it as text! Since it would take it as a date.

Example: b4(2 - 1) + c4(3 - 1) + d4(0 - 2). Then e4 would be 5 and f4 would be 4.

Can any give some hints, since i formattet it as tex[image]t?

To sum the numbers on left side and right side in 2 deffirent cells.

Comment: Can you please clarify where exactly the integers are going to come from? Do you mean leftmost and rightmost digits of a number?

Comment: Soory if it was unclear, so i print screened it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am at work and images are blocked in my browser so I can only take a stab at what you want. This does not need Excel VBA at all. Use the following formulas:

In E4: `=SUM(VALUE(LEFT(B4,1)),VALUE(LEFT(C4,1)),VALUE(LEFT(D4,1)))`

In F4: `=SUM(VALUE(RIGHT(B4,1)),VALUE(RIGHT(C4,1)),VALUE(RIGHT(D4,1)))`

Fill down if multiple rows.

Let us know if this helps. :)

EDIT: Just to give you a sample (which I won't see even if I posted it myself):

[image]

Comment: I already tried something like that, the problem is the separator, for that u used left and right, but it gives an error. Is the format the problem?

Comment: `=LEFT(x,1)` returns the first leftmost character of cell x. I see no reason why it should even touch the separator. `VALUE` converts it from text to a numeral value, so there is no problem with `SUM` either. What strings do you have exactly in B4, C4, and D4?

Comment: So lets say: C3(2 - 0) and D3(1 - 0). Then L3 should give 3 and M3 should give 0.

Comment: So the exact content of cell C3 is `(2 - 0)`? :)

Comment: If you're sure the formatting in cells C3 and D3 are text, try entering this into cell L3: `=SUM(VALUE(LEFT(C3,1)),VALUE(LEFT(D3,1)))`. What's the result?

Comment: Gives an error. C3 and D3 is text. What should L3 formattet as?

Comment: Since we can't move this to chat due to your low rep, we shall have to make do here. Try setting the format of L3 to General. The image I posted above is in General format for L3 while C3 and D3 are in text.

Comment: And that is what it is, but what kind of function should it be?

Comment: I can get it working with 1 cell, so think its the brackets, that has been the problem all the way:D

Comment: Yes, it is just a simple `SUM` as you can see from the formula. This is how it works. `LEFT` gets the leftmost character. In this case, that's `2` for cell C3. Then we convert it from text to number using `VALUE`. The last part is summing all converted first-characters. I don't understand how this is failing on your end.

Comment: Ah, so there are indeed brackets? Because you said there weren't any. :) So, just confirm. The EXACT content of C3 is `(2 - 0)`?

Comment: No the brackets inside the function:

Comment: If that's the case, you can actually remove `SUM` and just retain `=VALUE(LEFT(C3,1))+VALUE(LEFT(D3,1))`. :) In any way, if this helped you out, kindly accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark above. :)

Comment: This is wierd, i tried the same thing, that didnt work :D LOL

Comment: Eh? What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Well since everyone downvoted me, i can't vote you up (So to all of those people **** you) So sorry mate, that's why im against downvoting